# decision tree in matlab - change font size

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

Could someone please assist:

Is there a way to change font size of classregtree in matlab?
How can I change the class labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, try this:

using an example from the docs:

```
load fisheriris;

t = classregtree(meas,species,...
             'names',{'SL' 'SW' 'PL' 'PW'})
```

I was able to get the property-inspector:

```
tr=view(t)
inspect(tr)
```

..what didnt help a lot...

Now I took the handles of all children of tr, that are text-elements:

```
allHandles=findall(tr,'Type','text')
```

Next, I just changed the FontSize:

```
set(allHandles,'FontSize',16)
```

and there you go :) it is working!

To see and edit other properties, you could now use the inspect-method, as I was doing at my first try, but with the text-handles of course. normally, there should be all other properties available as for normal text-elements. Just check the docs for uicontrol + text.

Answer (score 0):

Lucius's answer worked for me but instead of

```
tr=view(t)
```

I had to run this:

```
before = findall(groot,'Type','figure'); % Find all figures
view(t,'Mode','graph')
after = findall(groot,'Type','figure');
tr = setdiff(after,before); % Get the figure handle of the tree viewer
inspect(tr)
```